# Liquibase 4.26 while importing the csv file it's taking long time

Tags: mysql, performance, liquid, csv-import, loaddata

I recently upgraded Liquibase from version 3.5.0 to 4.24.0 and am facing performance issues when loading data into a table. The data loading process, which was previously efficient, is now significantly slower. I am using Liquibase to load a CSV file with 40,000 rows into a MySQL database.

Here's the `changeSet` I'm using:

```xml
<changeSet id="5.3.1" author="siddharth" runInTransaction="true">
    <comment>Create zip_codes table</comment>
    <createTable tableName="zip_codes">
        <column name="uid" type="BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="zip_code" type="VARCHAR(15)">
            <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
        </column>
        <column name="longitude" type="DECIMAL(9,6)" />
        <column name="latitude" type="DECIMAL(9,6)" />
        <column name="created_at" type="DATETIME" />
        <column name="updated_at" type="DATETIME" />
    </createTable>
    <comment>Load zip_codes table</comment>
    <loadData tableName="zip_codes" file="db/changelog/data/db.changelog-5.3.1-zip-code-data.csv" quotchar='"'>
        <column name="ZIP_CODE" type="STRING" />
        <column name="LONGITUDE" type="NUMERIC" />
        <column name="LATITUDE" type="NUMERIC" />
        <column name="CREATED_AT" type="DATE" />
        <column name="UPDATED_AT" type="DATE" />
    </loadData>
    <rollback>
        <dropTable tableName="zip_codes" />
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, and share the code involved. If you are using any existing software, without having written any code on your own, such problems should be reported in the software's issue tracker

Comment: What old/new version of MySQL?

Comment: my sql 5.7 and new version is 8.But i am getting issue in both the version.